# How do I know which key combination does what for the Dvorak international alternative layout?

Tags: xkb, dvorak

So far, I can only figure it out by trial and error.

```
Right Alt + a = à
Right Alt + o = ô
Right Alt + e = é
Right Alt + u = û
Right Alt + i = î
Right Alt + 4 = €
Right Alt + , = ä
Right Alt + . = ê
Right Alt + p = ë
Right Alt + y = ü
Right Alt + ; = â
Right Alt + q = ö
Right Alt + j = è
Right Alt + k = ù
Right Alt + x = ï
Right Alt + c = ç
Right Alt + ` = dead `
Right Alt + 9 = dead `
Right Alt + ' = dead ´
Right Alt + " = dead ¨
Right Alt + < = dead ˇ
Right Alt + > = ·
Right Alt + p = dead ¸
Right Alt + 6 = dead ^
Right Alt + ^ = dead ^
Right Alt + s = ß
Right Alt + ] = dead ~
Right Alt + ~ = dead ~
Right Alt + Q = dead ˛
Right Alt + : = dead ˝
Right Alt + J = dead ˝
Right Alt + C = dead ˙

Right Alt + Q - Right Alt + X = Ǭ
```

There's more, but I haven't figured it out.

[update]

Thanks to Stephen Kitt, I solved it:

```
[me@MyComputer ~]$ sudo pacman -S libgnomekdb
...
[me@MyComputer ~]$ gkbd-keyboard-display -g 1
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the full layout definition in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` on your system. Looking at [the current upstream version](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xkeyboard-config/tree/symbols/us#n263) shows that, *e.g.*

- the top-left key produces <kbd>`</kbd> (dead), <kbd>~</kbd> with <kbd>Shift</kbd> (dead), <kbd>`</kbd> with <kbd>Alt</kbd> (not dead), and <kbd>~</kbd> with <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> (not dead)
- the next key produces <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>!</kbd>, <kbd>¡</kbd>, <kbd>¹</kbd> respectively

and so it goes.

If you’re running GNOME, you can [use the key map applet](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/290558/86440) to view the full keymap:

[image: Dvorak international keymap]